# Maxima abortion's shortcut after a syntax error

Tags: maxima

I apologize for this trivial question. Sometimes, after a syntax error, I am unable to return to Maxima's command prompt.

For example, after

```
2+2;]
```

how to return to the normal Maxima prompt without closing the terminal?

Ctrl-c does not work.  Ctrl-z does not work. Indeed after Ctrl-z then pressing Enter, we return to Maxima prompt, but I am unable to execute commands, even `2+2;` does not work.

To be precise, I work under Windows, and use Maxima, command line version.

Comment: Hi, are you working with wxMaxima or command line Maxima, or another user interface? Are you working on MS Windows, Linux, or macOS? Thank you for any information. Perhaps you can paste the output of `build_info();` into your question.

Comment: Thank you for the additional information. Try entering `0;` twice. `0;` is a valid input, and seeing the `;` and then `0;` can sometimes help the input parser get back on track. What happens if you enter `0;` twice?

Comment: @RobertDodier Thank you, entering `0;` just once helps.